# individual matplotlib graphs for a dataframe with tickers

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am trying to display individual plots for a dataframe which contains tickers. The dataframe has 5 tickers, i.e., 5 companies from NASDAQ using yahoofinance.

This is how the `all_data` dataframe looks like:

```
                   signal  short_mavg   long_mavg  positions
Ticker Date                                                 
AAPL   2020-01-02     0.0   75.087502   75.087502        NaN
       2020-01-03     0.0   74.722500   74.722500        0.0
       2020-01-06     0.0   74.798332   74.798332        0.0
       2020-01-07     0.0   74.748125   74.748125        0.0
       2020-01-08     0.0   74.958000   74.958000        0.0
```

the code to print the plots look like

```
fig = plt.figure()

# Add a subplot and label for y-axis
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,  ylabel='Price in $')

# Plot the closing price
all_data['Close'].plot(ax=ax1, color='r', lw=2.)

# Plot the short and long moving averages
signals[['short_mavg', 'long_mavg']].plot(ax=ax1, lw=2.)

# Plot the buy signals
ax1.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == 1.0].index, 
         signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == 1.0],
         '^', markersize=10, color='m')

# Plot the sell signals
ax1.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == -1.0].index, 
         signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == -1.0],
         'v', markersize=10, color='k')
         
# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The error is coming in line `ax1.plot(signals.loc[signals.positions == 1.0].index,  signals.short_mavg[signals.positions == 1.0], '^', markersize=10, color='m')`

and the error is `TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a tuple`

Help to create individual graph for each ticker would be much appreciated.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem of `matplotlib`. Looks like the `df` has multiple indexes.

In this case you should first select the correct index, instead of using as x coordinate `signals.loc[signals.positions == -1.0].index` you can use `signals.loc[signals.positions == -1.0].index.get_level_values(1)` (check that this is Date actually).

Also before plotting try to print the values that you are trying to plot to see if something weird is there. You want to make sure that x and y are actually lists, series of numbers and not lists of tuples for example.

Comment: Hi, basically I have 5 tickers, like AAPL, CPRI and all. I want to plot a line graph for each. Each line will be based on the "Close" column. The difficult part is trying to get the buy and sell arrow part implemented in the graph as having the ticker in dataframe is making it difficult with indexes.

Comment: The question is then ambiguos and not clear. The error that you are having is because of the multiple index in the df, basically you have 2 indexes.
The solution to the error is the one that I provided. If you want to do something else you should provide more info if not it is hard to help you and know which is your question.